# PHP multiple classes implementing same interface

Tags: php, oop

If I have an interface in PHP, say

```
interface AuthenticationInterface {
}
```

and two classes which implement the interface, for example

```
class ApiKey implements AuthenticationInterface {
}

class AuthToken implements AuthenticationInterface {
}
```

How is it determined which of these classes is used when a new AuthenticationInterface in instantiated?

Comment: You can't instantiate interfaces directly; you have to explicitly pick an implementing class to instantiate.

Comment: I don't get why you received a negative vote for the question. You are clearly new to programming and instead of receiving guidance, you get a negative mark. WTF Stackoverflow?

Comment: What is your real problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interfaces are used to define a structure(architecture) for classes that inherit it.

> An interface is a contract specifying a set of methods, fields and properties which will be available on any implementing object

I think you were interested in the class factory design pattern. Read more about it here: [php design patterns](http://www.phptherightway.com/pages/Design-Patterns.html)

Answer (score 0):

Interface can't be instantiated. You can create object of class.

Answer (score 0):

If your object was instantiated for you somewhere upstream and all you know is that it implements your AuthenticationInterface interface(so you know it can be one of a small number of classes...2 in your case), you can tell which class your object is by using "instanceof"

```
if ($your_object instanceof ApiKey)
{
    echo 'object class is ApiKey';
}
```